# How long is the Players' Turn?

Tags: mouse-guard

I recently finished reading the Player's Handbook (hare-riding, sword-wielding, caped mice — what more could I ask for?) and I'm having a hard time understanding the length of the Players' Turn.

Let's say that after the GM's Turn, everyone is Tired and doesn't have any checks other than the free ones. Let's say all the players say 'I try to recover'.
That's it? That's the end for the Players' Turn and we must go forward to the Rewards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Players' Turn can be very short, yes. It's a chance to roleplay a little bit of downtime and show off each mouse's personality, but in mechanical terms yes: the Players' Turn is over as soon as they've done their Checks. Players who want a longer Players' Turn need to earn more Checks during the GM's Turn!

When the Players' Turn is done you *don't* go directly to Rewards. Rewards are for the end of the session, but a session can have more than one GM's Turn and one Players' Turn. When the Players' Turn is done, normally another GM's Turn begins. You only go to Rewards if you've just finished the last Players' Turn of the session.

Comment: That's kind of a bummer... I expected the Player's turn to be a little longer, but I guess that my job as GM is to give plenty of opportunities for my players to get checks. Thanks for answering so fast!

Comment: @CuentaCuentos Yeah, and players also need to push themselves to get checks. They usually don't make this mistake more than once, because they'll want more opportunities to recover.

Comment: Yeah; Part of the "game" of the GM's turn is the players making/taking opportunities to earn checks if they want to have a longer players' turn.  You may need to remind them that it can be to their advantage to just hurt themselves for a check on a really hard roll instead of blowing a bunch of resources for a slim chance to pass it.